# Why exactly did Khrushchev present Pushinka to JFK's daughter Caroline?

Tags: history, russia, animals

Pushinka (*Fluffy*) was the name of one of the Strelka's (*Arrow's*) six pups that she had after being safely landed to Earth from orbit to which it was launched aboard Vostok-1K rocket No. 2 on 19 August 1960. Wikipedia describes this in a bit more detail in the [Soviet space dogs article, section on Belka and Strelka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_space_dogs#Belka_and_Strelka).

[image]

<sup>Kennedy family dog Pushinka on the White House North Lawn.</sup>

It is to my understanding that Chairman Nikita Khrushchev and US President John F. Kennedy maintained a rather warm relationship despite the cold war era already being at full swing, and they communicated regularly. BBC News magazine covers this [Pushinka: A Cold War puppy the Kennedys loved](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-24837199) story in even more detail and also republishing Kennedy's letter to Khrushchev upon receiving the pup:

[image]

<sup>Both above photographs courtesy of [John F. Kennedy Presidential Library & Museum](http://www.jfklibrary.org/).</sup>

It's a heartwarming story for sure, but what exactly were Khrushchev's intentions with it, besides, you know, *rubbing it in* that the Soviet communist space program was at that time more advanced than the *free world* capitalist one?

**Was this information ever disclosed to the public, perhaps in some memoirs / biography or analyzed in more detail by some cold war historian like Martin Sandler that the BBC article mentions?**

It was quite common in those times for such presents to have a hidden message to it, and I find the whole thing a bit curious to say the least. Was there a more obscure agenda behind this *present* to JFK's daughter Caroline? I guess it could be seen as a good will / public relations gesture of sorts, and that's I guess how it was received by the general public. But it could as well serve as a proof that the outer space isn't hostile to life on Earth? Or perhaps serve as any number of other messages that I can't think of.

Comment: Would be interesting to contact [Sergei Khrushchev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergei_Khrushchev) about it (e.g., through his literary agent/publisher).

Comment: Perhaps it was meant to serve as a reminder of the lives that would be lost in a nuclear war.

Comment: I always hoped it was so he could say to some of his more belligerent cronies back home *"Well, he keeps a dog, so he can't be **all** bad.."*

Comment: Because *space dog*. (I take it the dog was X-rayed by the CIA, purely as a precaution...)